# Isn't the chat's lobby footer supposed to be stuck on the bottom of the page?

Tags: bug, design

On every tab of the [**SO chat**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) where the boxes don't cover the whole page (usually favorite | events | mine), the footer is detached from the bottom (unlike when the boxes fill the entire area). It would look better always on the bottom regardless of it's content.

Check the gap on the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: I agree, as long as it does disappear when the content is long enough to push it down.