# Bad appearance on a high resolution screen

Tags: discussion, bug, design, footer

I've got a high resolution monitor (a 4K one) and I experience a really nasty behavior of the footer on any SO website when content is tiny enough. I use the Chrome browser on Windows 10 desktop.

Here is an illustration:

[image: Problem with the footer]

This does not make the website unusable, of course, but it is a bit annoying. Any chance that this will be fixed? :)

Comment: Probably not. The footer is not "stuck" to the bottom, so if you happen to have a window that is taller than the actual page content, then there will be blank space between the bottom of the footer and the bottom of the actual window. Users have been reporting the same issue with the chat footer for years ([most recent](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321653/isnt-the-chats-lobby-footer-supposed-to-be-stuck-on-the-bottom-of-the-page)).

Comment: @animuson yet everything is "fixable" right? Just depends on how much the project managers care about it

Comment: There will always be a blank when the window screen is taller than the page content. Here, it is before the end of the footer but it could be after the end of that footer, or before the whole footer. It's just an esthetical choice :)

Comment: maybe it is possible to change background to black and for content insert a div with withe background an no margins and paddings ?

Comment: This is what you get for having better screen than mine ;) One moment you feel sorry for having a plain old monitor and then you see the screenshot... Thank you lord (*and SE*) xD

Comment: Oh nice. question is marked as duplicate. Well, the wierd thing is there are two choices: "that solved my problem" and "no, my question is different", But neither is appropriate :) What do i choose guys? :)

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser It is not marked as dupe  yet. Some (`<5`) people voted as such. If you agree choose the first option, then community user will mark it as dupe. If you want to keep it open, choose the second one.

Comment: @animuson The question is... Why isn't it stuck to the bottom? And if it's not meant to be, why is there a black bar that _is_ stuck to the bottom?

Comment: What's the german word for 'combining the technologies of three or more competing companies and expecting an aesthetic experience.'

Comment: @Basic The black bar is not from us. Probably their taskbar or part of the browser window. Sticking things to the bottom is just a lot of work when the majority of pages will always be tall enough to make it unnecessary to do anyways.