# Footer isn't at foot on Stack Overflow Chat

Tags: bug, design, chat, footer

**Edit**: I have found the [dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321653/isnt-the-chats-lobby-footer-supposed-to-be-stuck-on-the-bottom-of-the-page?rq=1) of this question finally - but that question does not have the answer and is 2 years old. I am marking my question duplicate

The footer slides up in chat when there is no information available in the middle. See screenshots.

[image: Image 1]

In image 2 the footer tends to shift more upwards.

[image: Image 2]